Error of First Order Degradation
I ran an experiment based around the degradation of organic compounds under 4 treatments (hot + dark, light exposure + room temp, dark + room temp, cold + dark) for 8 compounds in 6 different aqueous matrices. The concentration of the compounds was taken at 3-time points using HPLC-MS/MS and measured in triplicate, producing 9 data points for each treatment + compound + matrix.
I have been of course able to produce the 192 graphs of the natural log-transformed concentrations versus time, my question is, what is the best way to calculate the error of the half-lives based on these linear regressions? My collaborators have had some concerns around calculating error of ln transformed data and stated SE cannot simply be used in this scenario.

why use linear regression? why not nonlinear direct fit to the exponential decay?

@Andrew I believe linear regression of the ln transformed concentration is the standard way to present first-order degradation but if I understand you correctly you're suggesting take the error of a exponential decay function fitted to the non-transformed data?

Yes. The linear fit of the transformed data is a nice way to present it visually, and you can do that with the results of the nonlinear fit, but the nonlinear fit is much better mathematically.  You may also find that three time points is not a sufficient sample size to get a good fit, but that's a separate issue.

One other thing to be aware of is that many basic "exponential" fits (for example Microsoft Excel) actually do the fit by linear regression of transformed data, so make sure to use a proper data fitting program like Kaleidagraph or SigmaPlot that does true nonlinear fitting or program it yourself in Excel (use solver for the minimization).


I have been of course able to produce the 192 graphs of the natural log-transformed concentrations versus time, my question is, what is the best way to calculate the error of the half-lives based on these linear regressions? My collaborators have had some concerns around calculating error of ln transformed data and stated SE cannot simply be used in this scenario.

First, I agree that nonlinear fitting is better than log-transformation and linear fitting.   See this old answer I wrote about a similar reciprocal transformation.
Second, you will still have a question about how to handle the distinct replicates and time points.  You could either:

average each time point across the three replicates (for each chemical and matrix), and then do nonlinear fitting on the time course that consists of averaged timepoints.
calculate non-linear fits for each replicate, and then average the best-fit half-lives across replicates.

Which is best depends a bit on how exactly your experiment worked: was timepoint #2, replicate #2 taken from the same tube or reaction as timepoints #1 for replicate #2?  If so, maybe the second approach is better.  If not (e.g. if each timepoints sample was it's own full reaction), maybe the first is better.

Not sure why you'd use averages in method #1. Using all the original three data points for each time in the fit preserves the information about the error at each time point. If you average, you should properly weight each averaged point according to its error which makes the fit more complicated.

I think method #1 might be better if the samples for each "timepoint" aren't actually from the same reaction.  For example, if to do three replicates of three timepoints by actually setting up nine reactions, and take the first time point by destructively and fully sampling the first three reactions, and the second time point by doing the same to reactions #4, 5, and 6, etc., then averaging first makes sense to me.
